# Python Scrapy not returning Chinese characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8, scrapy

I am scraping [this link](https://detail.1688.com/offer/544907042353.html) using Python Scrapy. All files have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the start

And to extract title of product, I have this code.

`response.css("h1.d-title::text").extract_first()`

This shows

```
2017\xe6\x98\xa5\xe5\xa4\x8f\xe6\x96\xb0\xe6\xac\xbe\xe5\xa5\xb3\xe5\xa3\xab\xe8\xbf\x90\xe5\x8a\xa8\xe9\x9e\x8b\xe9\x9f\xa9\xe7\x89\x88\xe4\xbc\x91\xe9\x97\xb2\xe7\xbd\x91\xe5\x8d\x95\xe9\x9e\x8bsport shoes men\xe5\xa4\x96\xe8\xb4\xb8\xe6\x89\xb9\xe5\x8f\x91
```

And if I do

`response.css("h1.d-title::text").extract_first().decode('gbk').encode('utf-8')`

Its giving me error

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-19: ordinal not in range(128)`

I have tried other alternatvies online but none of it worked.

Though if I do this in Python Terminal (Without Scrapy) it prints Chinese perfectly!.

```
>>> s = "2017\xe6\x98\xa5\xe5\xa4\x8f\xe6\x96\xb0\xe6\xac\xbe\xe5\xa5\xb3\xe5\xa3\xab\xe8\xbf\x90\xe5\x8a\xa8\xe9\x9e\x8b\xe9\x9f\xa9\xe7\x89\x88\xe4\xbc\x91\xe9\x97\xb2\xe7\xbd\x91\xe5\x8d\x95\xe9\x9e\x8bsport shoes men\xe5\xa4\x96\xe8\xb4\xb8\xe6\x89\xb9\xe5\x8f\x91"
>>> print s
2017春夏新款女士运动鞋韩版休闲网单鞋sport shoes men外贸批发
```

Why its giving correct output with `print`?

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy Selector will returns a list of unicode strings, refer to [Using selectors with regular expressions](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.2/topics/selectors.html?highlight=unicode#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions).  What you need to do is to encode the unicode to UTF-8, no need to decode to gbk then encode back to utf-8.

```
title = response.css("h1.d-title::text").extract_first().encode('utf-8')
```

For print in python terminal, i think the default encoding of your environment is UTF-8, you can enter your python terminal:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.stdout.encoding
UTF-8
```

when you print the unicode strings, it will convert to utf-8 then print out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example code with `print s` I assume you are using Python 2.7

When I ran

```
response.css("h1.d-title::text").extract_first()
```

on the site you listed I got this as a result:

```
u'2017\u6625\u590f\u65b0\u6b3e\u5973\u58eb\u8fd0\u52a8\u978b\u97e9\u7248\u4f11\u95f2\u7f51\u5355\u978bsport shoes men\u5916\u8d38\u6279\u53d1'
```

Means scrapy is already converting the result into an unicode object (that's what I would have expected).

Then running `decode('gbk')` on it will fail as decode tries to interpret it as being an gbk-encoded string.

So if you you need to convert it to utf-8 (instead of just using the unicode object, which I would prefer) you should do this:

```
response.css("h1.d-title::text").extract_first().encode('utf-8')
```

Result:

```
'2017\xe6\x98\xa5\xe5\xa4\x8f\xe6\x96\xb0\xe6\xac\xbe\xe5\xa5\xb3\xe5\xa3\xab\xe8\xbf\x90\xe5\x8a\xa8\xe9\x9e\x8b\xe9\x9f\xa9\xe7\x89\x88\xe4\xbc\x91\xe9\x97\xb2\xe7\xbd\x91\xe5\x8d\x95\xe9\x9e\x8bsport shoes men\xe5\xa4\x96\xe8\xb4\xb8\xe6\x89\xb9\xe5\x8f\x91'
```

Which prints the same string you expect.

Besides this it is usually a good idea to use Python3 as it handles most of such situations out of the box.